# How to manage shadow target of THREE.DirectionalLight

Tags: three.js, shadows

I use `three.js rev.76`

I don't know how to manage shadow target of `THREE.DirectionalLight`.

We can set position of `DirectionalLight` like:

```
dirLight.position.set(200, 1000, 200 );
```

But DirectionalLight will look at `(0.0.0)`, and shadow camera too. How i can make it to look at `(100.200.300)`?

Comment: i find some solution, it looks warking, but very ugly:

`var mid = new THREE.Object3D();`
`mid.position.x = 400;`
`dirLight.target=mid;`

Comment: Why not simply `dirLight.target.position.set( 100, 200, 300 );`?

Comment: @WestLangley because it doesn't work, and my solution doesn't work too.